# Why am I shown the Setup Screen (Choose Language) after every reboot?

Tags: reboot, language-support, setup

I get the setup screen where it asks me to choose language after I reboot the Ubuntu server. It happens after every reboot. How could I git rid of it?

Comment: What happens if you do choose a language?  And which Ubuntu server are you using?

Comment: Hope you don't have a bootable disk mounted on your machine and have its priority above the hard disk where your server is installed(?)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu 12.04 there was a bug with incomplete language support. Try running `check-language-support -l en` in your terminal (replace `en` with your current active locale). It will list all missing language packages for this locale. Install these packages using `sudo apt-get install` (you can copy the list from the output of the previous command) and reboot your system to check whether "Choose language" screen is gone.